# Meteor Helpers - a function to check if document exists

Tags: meteor

The following code works as intended, ie the helper returns true if there is a document and false if there is no document. However, i am getiing a warning on my console.

"Error: Exception in template helper:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'filepickerId' of undefined
    at Object.Template.navigation.helpers.ichk..."

The warning is inconsistent and not sure why that i the case. Once again, the code however works without any flow that i can tell.

```
Template.nav.helpers({

        'ichk': function(){

            var ct= Info.findOne({_id:Meteor.userId()});

            if (ct.profilepic.filepickerId) {
                return true;
            }else{
                return false;
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it works you should add one more line in order to get rid of the exception.

```
Template.nav.helpers({

       'ichk': function(){

        var ct= Info.findOne({_id:Meteor.userId()});

                if(ct){

                if (ct.profilepic.filepickerId) {

                return true;

                 }

                else{

                return false;

                }}
```

In this way you first check if the document exists.

Answer (score 2):

You need a [guard](http://dweldon.silvrback.com/guards). Your helper can be rewritten like this:

```js
Template.nav.helpers({
  ichk: function () {
    var ct = Info.findOne({ _id: Meteor.userId() });
    return !!(ct && ct.profilepic && ct.profilepic.filepickerId);
  }
}
```